# HttpClient request header customisation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

Is it possible to set the request ACCEPT header of the HttpClient in .Net/Web Api to include "application/json;odata=verbose"?

I know how to set the request media type

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);            
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

But how do I set the odata=verbose part?  I cannot seem to find any solutions online to do that.

Do I have to use HttpWebRequest instead?  Basically I need to call sharepoint 2013 rest api, and that odata=verbose part is required.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue` has a property called Parameters to which you can add 'odata=verbose' parameter.

Other easy way is to call `MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue`'s Parse/TryParse methods to which you can supply the whole "application/json;odata=verbose" media type string.

Here is an example using Parse

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    //Setup Accept Header
    MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue acceptHeader = MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json;odata=verbose");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(acceptHeader);

    //... do other stuff
}
```